# Retrieving Info from Text Box

Tags: javascript

I have been able to make some progress on a program but am running into a problem that I can't quite figure out. In the script, when the text box loses focus it is supposed to update the total cost. At this point it retrieves the number from the html code, but it is not retrieving the number that is input.

```
function productCosts()
{
    var totalMap = document.getElementById('qty1');
    var quantity1 = parseFloat($("qty1").value);
    var price1 = parseFloat($('price1').value);
    var totalMapBlur = function()
    {
        var totalMapCost = $('cost1');
        totalMapCost = (quantity1) * (price1);
        alert(price1);
        alert(quantity1);
        alert(totalMapCost);
    }
    qty1.onblur = (totalMapBlur);

}
```

I have created a fiddle so that you can see all of the code. http://jsfiddle.net/KRFjd/1/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S. If you feel my question is not written well enough, please let me know how to improve, don't just review the question negatively. I am trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you only set `quantity1`when you call `productCosts()` when the document is first loaded. You don't update it when the user edits the input field. And if you want the `Cost` column to be updated, you have to assign to its `value`.

```
var totalMapBlur = function()
{
    var quantity1 = $('qty1').value;
    var totalMapCost = (quantity1) * (price1);
    alert(price1);
    alert(quantity1);
    alert(totalMapCost);
    $('cost1').value = totalMapCost;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/KRFjd/2/)